# How to perform penetration testing of Blackberry mobile applications?

Tags: penetration-test, blackberry

I wish to start with blackberry mobile application penetration testing. 
I researched on net but no "in-depth" knowledge is available.

Here is a good article but not much is covered.
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/security-assessment-of-blackberry-applications/

I had a look at this question [BlackBerry handheld penetration testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12313/blackberry-handheld-penetration-testing)

The above question targets the handhelds and not a particular mobile app. 
It would be great to get any help regarding how to pentest blackberry mobile "app".

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's very nice blog that contains the answer ([cLick here](http://blog.attify.com/attifys-guide-to-get-started-with-pentesting-blackberry-apps/))

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the platform, a basic mobile penetration test should cover the [OWASP Top 10 for mobile](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#tab=Top_10_Mobile_Risks).